# Is it safe to use a char pointer in *argv[] directly in C?

Tags: c, getopt

I have the following code to get a string from a user with `getopt()` in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include "util.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        usage(); // from util.h
        return 0;
    }

    char *argument = NULL;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:"))) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'f':
            argument = optarg;
            break;
        }
    }
    // ... use `argument` with other stuff ...
}
```

Is this safe to do, or should I use `strcpy()` to copy the string into `argument`? If I accidentally change the contents of `argument`, could an attacker change stuff like environment variables?

Comment: `argv` are command line arguments to your program. How would expect making changes there to affect environment variables? And what kind of "attacker" are you talking about?

Comment: to use `strcpy()` the program must first allocate the needed amount of memory to hold the argument other wise the result of calling `strcpy()` would be undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:"))) {`  this will not detect the end of the arguments.  Strongly suggest" `while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:")) != 1 ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this safe to do, or should I use `strcpy()` to copy the string into argument?

It is safe to do, and `getopt()` is designed to be used that way.  More generally, the program arguments provided to main are specified to be writable strings belonging to the program.

Do note, however, that some `getopt()` implementations, notably GNU's, may reorder the elements of `argv`.

> If I accidentally change the contents of argument, could an attacker change stuff like environment variables?

The argument strings are susceptible to bounds overflow errors just like any other objects in the program.  If, through programming error or other means, your program attempts to write past the bounds of any object then the behavior is undefined.  Modification of environment variables is one of the more plausible members of the unbounded space of possible manifestations of UB.

Note, however, that making a copy of the arguments doesn't help in that regard.  You must avoid overrunning the bounds of any such copies, too, lest UB be triggered, with the same unbounded space of possible manifestations.

If you want to make sure that the program arguments cannot be modified via variable `argument`, then it would be idiomatic to declare it as a pointer to `const char` instead of a pointer to (modifiable) `char`.  That will not interfere with assigning the value of `optarg` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is "safe".

The contents of `argv` are supplied by the host environment, and belong to your process for its entire duration.

On [`argv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function):

> The strings are modifiable, and any modifications made persist until program termination, although these modifications do not propagate back to the host environment: they can be used, for example, with [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

With that said, privileged processes, like the `ps` utility, are generally capable of accessing the current values of `argv`. Using `argv` for sensitive information is ill advised.

See: [Hiding secret from command line parameter on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3830823/2505965) and [Can argv be changed at runtime (not by the app itself)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59986922/2505965) for security concerns.

---

Aside: [`getopt`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) returns an `int`. The distinction is important, because if `char` is unsigned, it cannot represent the terminating value:

> If all command-line options have been parsed, then getopt() returns -1.

You should use `int` to reliably test against this value, otherwise the loop will continue infinitely.

```
int ch;

while (-1 != (ch = getopt(argc, argv, ":f:")))
```

Comment: You might want to be more explicit about the requirement for `ch` to be defined as an `int` for the test to be reliable and portable.